# Mongodb Compass cannot be opened in Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: mongodb

Installed successfully MongoDB Compass on Ubuntu 18.10. But when I try to run it, it refuses to start without showing anything. I am a newbie in MongoDB. What to do?

Comment: I have the same problem, if I try to open from terminal I get this message: *Segmentation fault (core dumped)*.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try with following commands. These steps worked for me.

```
wget https://downloads.mongodb.com/compass/mongodb-compass_1.15.1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i mongodb-compass_1.15.1_amd64.deb
sudo apt --fix-broken install
sudo apt -y install libgconf2-4
mongodb-compass;
```

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 18 with mongodb-compass_1.20.1_amd64.deb .

Comment: Yes.. seems 1.15.1 has some issues with latest versions of Ubuntu.. Has issues with Ubuntu 19.10 eoan. Tried with 1.20.1

Comment: When I download mongodb compass for ubuntu if shows this file is harm for your computer.

Answer (score 24):

Try these command in terminal :

1.
$ wget https://downloads.mongodb.com/compass/mongodb-compass_1.12.1_amd64.deb; (Try to get the latest one)

2.
$ sudo dpkg -i mongodb-compass_1.12.1_amd64.deb

3. ```
    $ mongodb-compass;
   ```

Worked for me.I'm also using Ubuntu 18.10

(Try to change the version of the mongodb compass - lower than 15-
v)

Comment: Thank you Nimesh. It worked but I need minimum 1.15.1 and theres already 1.16.0 released. How to get them?

Comment: `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. After following the exact same thing on the Mongo official website, [MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/master/install/), I have the above error! Please, any solution to this? Reading around, I saw it means it's trying to access an area of memory it doesn't have permission to.

Comment: Thanks Nimesh.  I had to perform one extra step to get mine to work.  Adding it here as it may be convenient for people who had the same issue as me.

```sudo apt install libgtk2.0-0:i386```

Reference: https://askubuntu.com/questions/836142/error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libgtk-x11-2-0-so-0-no-such-file-or-direc answer by https://askubuntu.com/users/256317/fkraiem.

Comment: Perfect. The latest 1.16.x version would give me about 10 seconds of UI time after the loading screen then hangup requiring a process kill.

Comment: Works fine on 1804 LTS too

Comment: HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden, cannot download it

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue with ubuntu 18.10. This issue still exists with versions 15 and 16. Earlier versions works fine in ubuntu 18.10.

1) wget https://downloads.mongodb.com/compass/mongodb-compass_1.14.1_amd64.deb

2) sudo dpkg -i mongodb-compass_1.14.1_amd64.deb

3) mongodb-compass

Comment: Does not work, computer says no: HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden

Comment: The new download url is https://downloads.mongodb.com/compass/mongodb-compass_1.14.1_amd64.deb

Answer (score 6):

We just released Compass 1.18-beta.1, Compass will work again on Ubuntu 18.10 and other recent Linux distributions. You can download it from here: https://www.mongodb.com/download-center/compass.

Comment: This produces a 403 (https://downloads.mongodb.com/compass/beta/mongodb-compass-beta.2.18.0~beta.2_amd64.deb).

Comment: @Massimiliano Marcon I've tried on Ubuntu 19.04 64x, it works. Thank you for this update.

Comment: @Massimiliano Marcon for me the current stable version `1.28.1` is not opening over ssh in `vscode`.  It is showing this error : `(mongodb-compass:7866): Gtk-WARNING **: 03:35:44.937: cannot open display: ` whereas the GUI is opening in the VM itself.

Comment: @y_159 do I understand correctly that you have ssh-ed into a the machine where Compass is installed and then you ran `mongodb-compass` from the shell? If that is the case, then it can't work: as the errors says, there is no display that can be used to open Compass (or any other tool with a UI). You can probably set up X11 forwarding but that might be a bit of a hassle.

Comment: @MassimilianoMarcon yes this is the case. I'm on windows 10 platform and using `vscode` to ssh to the ubuntu VM created inside virtualbox.

Answer (score 4):

Try these command in terminal :

```
wget https://downloads.mongodb.com/compass/mongodb-compass_1.14.1_amd64.deb;
sudo dpkg -i mongodb-compass_1.14.1_amd64.deb;
mongodb-compass;
```

try to use version less then 15.It solved my issue.

Answer (score 2):

It is not allowed  to download a full version on this way, it can only be done for the community versions, f.e:

1) wget https://downloads.mongodb.com/compass/mongodb-compass-community_1.15.1_amd64.deb

This you can download, but has the same problem.

I downloaded the mongodb-compass-community_1.12.1_amd64.deb with wget. I installed it with dpkg -i, and it works.

Answer (score 2):

Almost the same solution for Ubuntu 20.04

```
wget https://downloads.mongodb.com/compass/mongodb-compass_1.21.1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i mongodb-compass_1.21.1_amd64.deb
sudo apt --fix-broken install
mongodb-compass
```

Comment: fix-broken did nothing for me , but install 1.22.1 was good enough

Answer (score 1):

After installing the dpkg, need to run the following commands from the terminal

```
 1. sudo apt --fix-broken install
 2. sudo apt -y install libgconf2-4
 3. mongodb-compass;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have run the following commands in ubuntu 20.04 and successfully:

1. `sudo wget https://downloads.mongodb.com/compass/mongodb-compass_1.29.6_amd64.deb`
2. `sudo apt install --fix-broken install`
3. `sudo dpkg -i mongodb-compass_1.29.6_amd64.deb`
4. `mongodb-compass`

I hope this will help someone else there.

Comment: This answer seems to be the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61729449/4385621)

Comment: @gmauch i think it's not the same as all because when i use that one. i see it's not work for me and when i try to change the order and i see it worked as my expected. So not the same as all